# people in this country are/people are in this country

Tags: word-order

> 1 I know what people **in** this country **are**.
>
> 2 I know what people **are in** this country.

It seems to me that the sentences can have different meanings. But I can't pinpoint the difference explicitly. Are there two meanings or am I wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to find a credible semantic distinction with [TO BE] as in your example. But we could in principle distinguish between, say, #1: *what people **here need*** and #2: *what people **need here***. With that pair, feasibly #1 might refer to people who are *normally* here (because they *live* here), where #2 is more likely to refer to people who are *temporarily* here (on holiday, for example). But oftentimes no difference is intended or perceived. Syntactically, it's probably a matter of whether ***here*** adjectivally modifies ***people*** or adverbially modifies ***need***.

Comment: Hi. What is the context here?  What do you know that people **are**?  Do you live in "this country"?  Are you a visitor?  Is it something unpleasant? Something about their nature/character? Is it something about their nationality/ethinic origin? Meanings often depend on context. Without context, all we can really do is guess.

Comment: You might know something in country X but not know it in country Y, although that seems unlikely in most contexts. But maybe you lose your powers to think, reason, or remember in Y because of some quality it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without context, it's impossible to say the intended meaning or if there will be any meaningful difference between the two.

There could be a distinction between defining "*people in this country*" and defining "*people*" within the context of this country.

For instance if the definition of a "person" is different in this country than elsewhere, then sentence 2 would apply better.

But if the intent is to say you know the nature of all the people in this country, then both sentence work fine.